# Terraform Regular Expression

Tags: regex, terraform

I want to make a regular expression in terraform. So that the string is:

```
REGION-POLICY-NAME-TYPE-policy.json
```

Being Region:

- `GLB`
- `XS`
- or `XN`

Being POLICY_NAME: any character

and being TYPE:

- `ACL`
- or `WAF_RULE`

I have done something like this:

`"(?P<region>(GLB|XS|XN))-(?P<name>[0-9A-Za-z_])+)-(?P<type>(ACL|WAF_RULE))-policy.json"`

And now what I want is to get the name. And I've done:

```
for_each = fileset("${path.module}/../../policies-json/waf_rule/", "*-policy.json")
name = regex(basename(each.value), local.policy_filename_regex).name
```

I have received this error:

```
│ Error: Error in function call
│ 
│   on modules/policy_generator/main.tf line 4, in resource "incapsula_policy" "ACL_policies":
│    4:     name = regex(basename(each.value), local.policy_filename_regex).name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ while calling regex(pattern, string)
│     │ each.value is "GLB-CloudflarePolicyArDevSdstg-ACL-policy.json"
│     │ local.policy_filename_regex is "^(?P<region>(GLB|XS|XN))-(?P<name>[_a-zA-Z0-9]+)-(?P<type>(ACL|WAF_RULE))-policy.json$"
│ 
│ Call to function "regex" failed: pattern did not match any part of the given string.
```